Finding own input when purpose is spending, and understanding how validators are executed
When consuming a UTxO sitting at a smart contract script address, I frequently see variations of the following utility function to find the associated input
fn own_input(purpose: ScriptPurpose, inputs: List<Input>) {
   expect Spend(out_ref) = purpose 
   expect Some(found_input) = list.find(inputs, fn (input) { out_ref == input.output.reference }) 
 found_input 
}

I understand that one transaction may be attempting to consume multiple UTxOs. But I don't understand why we must search over our list of inputs. My mental model is each UTxO we want to consume, only the associated validator logic that locks it (or required signatory) is checked, depending on where the UTxO resides. So if we already know purpose is Spend(out_ref), then this out_ref currently being processed must be ours. Then why not just match Spend(found_input) more directly and skip the list.find? Because why would the current valdiator logic even execute for other input UTxOs that are not even being locked by it (sitting somewhere else)?
